# Number of files containing a given string

Tags: bash, grep, pipe

I want to show text files that contain a string and to count them. 
My code is:

```
grep -l "string" file1.txt file2.txt | wc -l
```

It shows the number of files that contain "string". How can I show the names of the files too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `tee`ing it?

```
grep -l 'string' file1.txt file2.txt | tee >(wc -l)
```